# Badges Overflow

Tags: bug, design, user-card

User badges (moderator and staff) overflow the revision container on `/posts/<id>/revisions` pages:

[image: 6th revision of a post showing a long moderator username with a mod badge on the right overflowing the container]

The issue is [spotted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297598/revisions) on Meta Stack Overflow, but since this pertains to the design common for all sites, I believe the bug to be network-wide.

The overflow happens since the flex container is structured as follows and does not have flex wrapping enabled:

[image: usercard line with the flex container structure highlighted]

One potential solution would be adding a [`fw-wrap`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/#flex-wrap) [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/) class (that sets a [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) CSS property to `wrap`) to the container that allows the items to wrap, but, unfortunately, due to "edited N ago" being a top-level item of the usercard, this yields a subpar, albeit a bit better, result:

[image: usercard line wrapping into 2 lines with flex-wrap enabled]

A perfect solution would be wrapping the user icon, name, and badges in a subcontainer, making it a flex container itself, and enabling flex wrapping for top-level items:

[image: example usercard line wrapped into 2 lines in a flex subcontainer]

For extremely narrow screens, it would also make sense to wrap the badge item to the next line:

[image: example usercard line wrapped into 3 lines in a flex subcontainer]

Comment: Hmm.. I can't seem to reproduce this on Chrome for Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8udhn.jpg

Comment: @Justin the screen needs to be narrower than that :) It's not mobile-specific, it's an oversight of handling narrow viewports - you can reproduce it on desktop by opening devtools and playing around with the viewport width.

Comment: It's not overflowing, on the contrary, it's **not** overflowing to more lines as it should (it's working fine in wide view), i.e. it's hidden.

Comment: More like it's not wrapping where it should, but yeah, I was looking for an excuse for a punny title mostly when using "overflow" :)

Comment: My FireFox on MacOS won't get small enough to reproduce it. I am reproducing it on Chrome on Android though.